# add color to VBOs - best practices

Tags: opengl, vbo

I am working on a visualisation engine (simple CAD style) (with python and pyopengl bindings) that will display and animate up to 10-20 bodies simultaneously. 
I am using VBO data objects to store vertex data and to display each body. I would like to know what is the best (most practical, easiest and less expensive-GPU) method to assign color to a VBO. Each body has uniform color and the appearance can be set to transparent - optional. As I know this can be done with the following methods (I tested method 1 and 2):

1. glColorf(R, G, B, A)
2. glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, , [R, G, B, A])
3. assign color to each vertex and create interleaved VBO

Are there any other methods? And which one is most suited for the job?
I would also like to ask how many vertices per VBO are recomended for one VBO and how many vertices have, lets say; small, medium and large VBOs? Just to give me more knowledge about size of the displayed objects.

Comment: The first two are deprecated and unavailable in OpenGL 3.2+ core. The third is the best intermediate approach, but ideally what you would really do is use vertex shaders for this. You could do something like assign each set of vertices in your VBO an index to identify the object they belong to, and then in a vertex shader assign color to each object by looking something up in a uniform array or texture. You should be really be thinking of the number of objects drawn per-batch, rather than the number of vertices per-object; in the end, you can usually draw multiple objects in one call.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, if I create a VBO that has (for example, in my case) 5000 vertices and I have to add a color vector (3 or 4 components) to every vertex and that increases the VBO size by factor 2 or 1,25. Is this economic as the color vector is equal for all vertices? Or is there another way to add color to VBO?
If I understand correctly this method is good if I would have FEM results (of every node/vertex) to display it as colors, right?

Answer (score 1):

The coloring part depends on which version of OpenGL you are using now, which version in the future, and whether or not you want lighting.

If you are using OpenGL 2.1, perhaps because you like having a built in matrix stack and gluPerspective, then glColor4f is the easiest way to set the uniform color for a non-lit object. If you want to use lighting, add a glColorMaterial call as well. Or for lighting you could use glMaterial.

As Andon points out, these will stop working if you have to move to OpenGL 3 or 4. So if this program is going to be updated in the future, or you have plans to add extra capabilities based on programmable GPU shaders, grab a copy of the OpenGL SuperBible 6th ed and start coding. The easiest way will be to add another VBO with per-vertex colors, or interleave colors with VBO as you've already discovered. In theory this is wasting space because a single color gets duplicated many times, but if you're not changing the color every frame, so what? (Gigabyte graphics cards are wonderful.)

OK, the recommended number of vertexes per VBO. Again, do you care? You say you have 10 - 20 objects to be rendered. That's not an excessive number of OpenGL calls per frame. Perhaps if you needed to render thousands of objects per frame it would be worth thinking about, but my advice is always to do the simplest thing that works first, because very often that's fast enough.

To get maximum performance from OpenGL you generally need to minimise the number of calls per frame. So if you have too many individual OpenGL calls, it doesn't really matter whether the data is one big VBO or lots of little ones. Stuffing more data into big VBOs (read up on primitive restart) usually does allow you to reduce the number of calls, and modern graphics cards let you store megabytes or even gigabytes per VBO. Read Real-Time Rendering by Moller and Haines, or the indirect drawing section of the SuperBible for more detail.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using some built-in matrix manipulation functions like `glTranslate`,`glRotate`,`glMultMatrixf`,`glPushMatrix`, `glPushMatrix`, etc as I have parallel (orthogonal) projection view and I use this for pan/zoom/rotate.
I am also using the VBO to store vertex data of each body. As I understand I can create another BO to store color vector of each vertex. But can I only save one color vector and say that this color is assigned to every vertex or does every vertex has to have new color vector?

Comment: About OpenGL compatibility. I use Radeon HD6300M (GL ver.: 4.2.12217 Compatibility Profile Context 12.104.0.0) and all is working OK. Does not newer versions of OpenGL also support functions from all previus versions? Or am I missing something. Thanks for the clear explanations :)

Comment: To have a single color for every vertex in new-style OpenGL 3 or 4 you'd have to make it a uniform. Every vertex in a VBO has to have a corresponding color value (surface normal, tex coord, ...) even if they are all the same.

Comment: Can this (single color for every vertex) be done in OpenGL 3.0 or lower (without using shaders)? I have geometry data from .stl file that has 3 vertices and 1 normal per triangle. Is this OK, or I need normal for every vertex?